# Show the date using JavaScript alert function

Tags: javascript, alert

I want to show the date in an alert in JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

alert(date());

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a new `Date` object and pass it to `alert()`

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   alert(new Date());
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
alert(new Date());
</script>
```

Learn more about Js date [js date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: Why would you use implicit global variables or link to W3Schools _or_ answer a question that has zero research effort where the OP didn’t even do a simple Google search?

Comment: to make him understand how we gate the date  `new Date()` and the link to give him more information about the  ways of instantiating a date

Comment: @AnonyPIng—there are vastly better resources than w3schools, such as the ECMAScript standard, W3C and MDN.